# Ruby Make Dir.glob works on path including tilde ~

Tags: ruby, path, tilde

I got a nil return when `Dir.glob("*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)` meet to a filepath that contains tilde like that :

```
  ~setup~.mak                            253.0 B
```

This is the entire instruction :

```
l = 
  Dir.
    glob("*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).
    tap { |a| a.shift(2) }.
    map { |p,i| p.force_encoding('utf-8')}.
    sort_by { |d| File.mtime(d) }.reverse!
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with tildes.

`Dir::glob` does not promise to return a sorted list. I suspect your `shift(2)` is intended to get rid of `.` and `..` but they are not the first two items in the list. Also, you do not need to use *banged* version of `reverse` to reverse inplace.

Reject these phantom directories explicitly:

```
  Dir.
    glob("*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).
    reject { |a| a =~ /\A\.+\z/ }. # ⇐ THIS
    map { |p, i| p.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) }.
    sort_by { |d| File.mtime(d) }.
    reverse

  # $ touch ~setup~.mak
  # $ ruby -e 'puts Dir.glob("*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).reject { |a| a =~ /\A\.+\z/ }'
  #⇒ ~setup~.mak
```

Comment: To avoid `.` and `..` just leave out the `File::FNM_DOTMATCH` argument.